# NetSuite: Getting the shipcity from a salesorder in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

If I load a sales order using the code below, how do I get the `shipcity`. Note that if you dump the object (salesOrder) you will see that there is NO `shipcity`. Whats strange is that `shipzip`, `shipstate` and `shipcountry` have their own fields but `shipcity` does not. I also tried `billcity` but to no avail. This seems like a big disconnect. The `shipcity` should say `Fort Wayne` like it does in the UI but the 2.0 API returns nothing

```
// load up a sales order from a Fort Worth customer
var salesOrder = record.load({
   type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
   id: salesOrderId,
   isDynamic: true
});

// these work fine
salesOrder.getValue("shipcountry") = "US"
salesOrder.getValue("shipstate") = "IN"
salesOrder.getValue("shipzip") = "46804"

// none of the following work when it should say "Fort Wayne"
salesOrder.getValue("shipcity") = Null
salesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: "shipcity" }) = Null
salesOrder.getText("shipcity") = Null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just confirmed it. With SS1.0 we can have value for 'shipcity' but not with SS2.0 for some reason. So let's get it with different approach using 'N/search' module. You may either create a search or do lookup. But I would suggest you to use lookup since you are just getting value at the header. Please try sample code below:


By the way, please hard code the value for type and don't use 'search.Type.SALES_ORDER'. For some reasons, it will error out.

```
require(
[
    'N/search'
], function(search)
{
var objFieldLookUp = search.lookupFields(
    {
        type : 'salesorder',
        id : 34826,
        columns :
            [
                    'shipcountry', 'shipstate', 'shipzip', 'shipcity'
            ]
    });

var stCountry = objFieldLookUp["shipcountry"];
var stState = objFieldLookUp["shipstate"];
var stZip = objFieldLookUp["shipzip"];
var stCity = objFieldLookUp["shipcity"];
});
```